# Is it wrong to favorite your own posts?

Tags: discussion, bookmarks

Is it okay to favorite one's own question in the hopes that it will influence people's voting?

Comment: In short: no, it's not wrong, and also no, it does not influence people's voting. It's just used to help you track changes better.